# diffrent between NSLog and -print description- with NSString and UTF-8

Tags: objective-c, ios4, xcode4, nsstring

I'm confused. I'm parsing json string.

Before parsing, I check what is the content of the `NSString`.

In `Xode4`:
When I click on the `NSString` variable "print description"
The console show the value as `\u434 \u433` format of the UTF-8

When I call `NSLog("%@",content)` the console show the "readble" character of the UTF-8 encoding.

Why is this different? How can I know that the string I got to parse is 100% UTF-8 ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you figured out the difference?

Answer (score 0):

If you can see the Cyrillic characters you're looking for, rather than the escapes, through **any** method, then you're working with a UTF-8 string.

The "-description" method is not what you want to use here. It's more likely to show escaped characters; in particular, any time you store a value in a property list item like an NSArray or NSDictionary, its -description will generally escape any characters other than plain ASCII.

NSLog is a more reliable guide, because it doesn't use -description. If it's showing up in NSLog, it's probably just fine.

If you want to be absolutely sure your string is properly encoded UTF-8, the best way to test it is to display it. Create a text interface element (an NSTextField or UITextField) in your user interface, wire it up, and set your string as the value. If it displays there, it is properly formatted.

**Short version**: if it shows up in the debugger as escaped characters, it doesn't necessarily mean it's not UTF8. If it's showing up anywhere (including NSLog) with the proper characters, it's probably in the proper encoding. If you want to be sure, set up a test interface element and see how it looks there.